# zend framework 2 - best method for respond an error message

Tags: jquery, error-handling, zend-framework2, httpresponse

I have this code in a Action method of my controller:

```
    $session = new Container('user');
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    if (!$session->offsetExists('userId')) {
      return $response->setContent(-1);
    }
    else //Correct response code
```

In my View, I detect the error using jquery/javascript and ajax so, and it works well.

```
    function anyfunction(drawId) {
      $.post('controller/action', '&param1=X', function(data) {
        if (data == -1) document.error.innetHTML = 'user no logued';
        else //correct response
      }
    }
```

I wand change my method because I like send the message from controller.
I need send some indicator, so that the view knows the response is a error.
I've thought about using of $response->setMetaData() mothod, but I don't know if it serves for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST use proper HTTP status codes with body optionally containing error description.
In this case code is <s>[401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.2)</s>
Actually, 401 is not suitable as it requires WWW-Authenticate header. 403 Forbidden should be used then.

Additionaly i'll suggest you to learn about:

1. JSON format, native for javascript and supported by ZF2 MVC with json view strategy.
2. RESTful APIs. If it will not be used, it still will give you idea how to use HTTP properly. You might want to read this [blog post and comments](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)
3. Take a look at this ietf draft: [Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-02) This draft is not standard in any way, currently, but it can give you some ideas.

Update:

I feel like i should add clarifications as answer is incomplete.
In addition to status code you will usually need to generate response body with extra details, may be in accordance with draft mentioned above.
As Zf2 is very flexible, there is no set way to do something. In one of the possible approaches you will need listener on `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` to detect unauthenticated/unauthorized access and trigger `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` event.
Take a look at BjyAuthorize module. You can use it.

And you will need listener on `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` to prepare proper response.
[You can use this as example](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/src/BjyAuthorize/View/UnauthorizedStrategy.php) At minimum ViewModel should be replaced with properly populated JsonModel. Also you will need registered json view strategy to make it work.

Comment: +1 Are you suggesting that along with ViewJsonStrategy we are supposed to communicate errors using HTTP Status Codes rather than custom JSON messages? I wish we could get a confirmation of this intent from ZF2 creators.

Comment: I am suggesting that main indicator of error is HTTP status code. And response body may be present, with details of that error. However, if we take example from the question, HTTP status code is all he needs.